# Simulating p-values as a function of sample size

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

We are trying to prove a very subtle effect occurring in cells after a certain treatment.  Let's assume that the measurements are normally distributed. Let's also assume the untreated cells have $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 0.1$ and the treated cells have $\mu = 1.1$ and $\sigma = 0.22$. The question is:

How large must the sample size be in order for the observed effect to be statistically significant ($\alpha = 0.05$)?

I know that very subtile effects require a larger sample size than more apparent effects, but how many? I'm still learning statistics, so please be patient with me. I tried to perform a little simulation in R. Assuming that you randomly pick $n$ samples from a normal distribution, I tried to calculate the mean p-value as a function of $n$.

[image]

Is this a correct way to do find the right sample size? Or am I completely off the track with this approach?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ctrl.mean <- 1
ctrl.sd <- 0.1
treated.mean <- 1.1
treated.sd <- 0.22

# Function that repeats t-test a number of times (rpt) with given sample size, means and sds.
# Returns a list of p-values from the test

tsim <- function(rpt, n, mean1, sd1, mean2, sd2) {
  x <- 0
  ppool <- NULL
  while (x <= rpt) {
    ppool <- c(ppool, t.test(rnorm(n,mean1,sd1), y = rnorm(n,mean2,sd2))$p.value)
    x <- x + 1
  }
  return(ppool)
}

# Iterate through sample sizes and perform the function
# Returns data frame with list of mean p-values at a given sample size

i <- 2
num <- 50
res <- NULL

while (i <= num) {
  sim <- tsim(1000, i, ctrl.mean, ctrl.sd, treated.mean, treated.sd)
  res <- rbind(res, cbind(i, mean(sim), sd(sim)))
  i <- i + 1
}

# Plot the result

res <- as.data.frame(res)

ggplot(res, aes(x=i, y=-log10(V2))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=-log10(V2)-log10(V3), ymax=-log10(V2)+log10(V3)), alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate("segment", x = 6, xend = num, y = -log10(0.05), yend = -log10(0.05), colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text",  x = 0, y=-log10(0.05), label= "p = 0.05", hjust=0, size=3) +
  annotate("segment", x = 6, xend = num, y = -log10(0.01), yend = -log10(0.01), colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text",  x = 0, y=-log10(0.01), label= "p = 0.01", hjust=0, size=3) +
  annotate("segment", x = 6, xend = num, y = -log10(0.001), yend = -log10(0.001), colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text",  x = 0, y=-log10(0.001), label= "p = 0.001", hjust=0, size=3) +
  xlab("Number of replicates") +
  ylab("-log10(p-value)") +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have almost performed what is usually called a [power analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power). I say almost, because what you usually measure in a power calculation is not the mean p-value, but rather the probability that, given the sample size and the hypothesised mean difference, you would get a p-value lower than say 0.05.

You can make small changes to your calculations in order to get this probability, however. The following script is a modification of your script that calculates the power for sample sizes from 2 to 50:

```
ctrl.mean <- 1
ctrl.sd <- 0.1
treated.mean <- 1.1
treated.sd <- 0.22

n_range <- 2:50
max_samples <- 50
power <- NULL
p.theshold <- 0.05
rpt <- 1000

for(n in n_range) {
  pvals <- replicate(rpt, {
    t.test(rnorm(n,ctrl.mean, ctrl.sd), y = rnorm(n, treated.mean, treated.sd))$p.value
  })
  power <- rbind(power, mean(pvals < p.theshold) )
}

plot(n_range, power, type="l", ylim=c(0, 1))
```

[image: power analysis]

The way I would read this graph goes like: "Given my assumptions of the two groups, the probability that I would find a significant effect at n = 30 is roughly 50%". Often an 80% chance of finding an actual effect is considered a high level of power. By the way, power analysis is generally considered *a good thing*. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was surprised to find out that I did a kind-of power analysis without knowing. :-) Statistics is more intuitive than I thought.

Comment: I would say it is often intuitive, but unfortunately hidden by a thick coating of arithmetics and mathematical notation... :)

Comment: @RasmusBååth, hey, I´m looking for improving a code inspired on your reply. Could you please check it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215958/sample-size-p-values-its-relationship-and-data-visualization-with-plots-ggp